# Mixture of 2 uniform random variables

Tags: r, uniform, mixture

I need help creating a mixture that is 1/3 Unif (0,7) and 2/3 Unif(9,10)
I used

```
library(distr)

X <- UnivarMixingDistribution(Unif(0,7),Unif(9,10),mixCoeff = c((1/3),(2/3)))
```

But I'm not sure if it is good because when plotting X, it returns a scatterpoint that does not really make any sense .

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: *"it returns a scatterpoint that does not really make any sense"* How did it not make sense? What was your expected output plot?

Comment: @MauritsEvers well already there shouldnt be any values between 7 and 9

Comment: You're very welcome @JaelNguyen!

Comment: @JaelNguyen ; can you show how you are generating values : as `plot(X)` shows zero density between 7 and 9, also no contribution towards the cdf here, and generating random numbers seems to have the required gap (`X@gaps`) : `hist(X@r(1e5))` ( `y = X@r(1e5) ; table(y > 7 & y < 9)` )

Comment: The code you provided does what you say you wanted it to do. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the function `distr::UnivarMixingDistribution` but this is easy to implement from scratch:

1. We fix the seed for reproducibility

   ```
   # Set fixed seed
   set.seed(2017);
   ```
2. Specify the number of sampling points

   ```
   # Sample N points
   N <- 1000;
   ```
3. Specify the mixing factors and limits of both uniform distributions

   ```
   # Weights and limits of both uniform distibutions
   weights <- c(1/3, 2/3);
   range <- list(list(min = 0, max = 7), list(min = 9, max = 10));
   ```
4. We now sample `N` points

   ```
   # Sample
   x <- unlist(mapply(function(x, y) runif(x * N, y$min, y$max), weights, range))
   ```
5. Let's plot the distribution of `x`

   ```
   ggplot(data.frame(x = x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 100)
   ```

[image]